# How to install and configure acts-as-dag rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to use acts-as-dag gem https://github.com/resgraph/acts-as-dag. Have created two models one for nodes(Learn::Graph::Node) and another for links(Learn::Graph::Edge)

which are described below

```
class Learn::Graph::Node < ApplicationRecord
 has_dag_links :link_class_name => 'Learn::Graph::Edge'
 acts_as_dag_links :node_class_name => 'Learn::Graph::Edge'
end

class Learn::Graph::Edge < ApplicationRecord
    acts_as_dag_links :node_class_name => 'Learn::Graph::Node'
end
```

so when i try to do pry(main)> Learn::Graph::Node.first in rails console i am getting below error

**ArgumentError: The scope body needs to be callable.
from /bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:165:in `scope'**

Any help or hint what could be wrong with the setup would be of great help.
Thanks

Comment: The latest release of that gem was 7 years ago so you're bound to run into compatiblity issues.

Comment: @max yes but i need a gem to work with directed acyclic graph and this one seems quite relevant but not maintained :(

Comment: Sorry but I don't really know the domain well enough to recommend an alternative. In my experience it could be really easy to fork and fix the gem or it could be way more work then just writing "bespoke" application code to solve the issue.

Comment: I think the gist of the issue is that earlier versions of AR allowed you to use strings to define scopes but you now need to use a lambda or proc.

Comment: @max Any fix apart from fork that you can suggest?

Comment: The alternative to forking is monkeypatching, but you're most likely going to need to do such extensive changes that it would be better to just fork - or find another solution.